# Установка библиотеки php_oci8.dll

Tags: php, apache, oracle

Мне необходимо подключить библиотеку php_oci8.dll для связи php c Oracle 9. Саму библиотеку скачала с официального сайта, строчку **extension=php_oci8.dll** в php.ini раскомментировала, в переменной Path все необходимые пути прописала, но при рестарте Apache он все равно говорит о невозможности загрузить эту библиотеку.

Что можно сделать, чтобы это исправить?

P.S.БД доступна с web-сервера, на машине стоит php версии 7 и Apache24

Comment: С помощью программы Dependency Walker, выяснила, что для данной библиотеки  отсутствует связь с ora.dll, а точнее отсутствует вход в одну из функций. Замена ora.dll результатов не дала(

Comment: Так и не поняла в чем было дело, но проблему решила установкой Apache22 и php 5.4.0. В качестве клиента Oracle использовалась 11 версия.